# Create a POSModel object in C# using OpenNLP library

Tags: c#, .net, ikvm, opennlp

I am using the IKVM tool for using OpenNLP library in .NET with C#. When I try to create an Object of

```
string pos = "\\en-pos-maxent.bin";
modelInpStream = new java.io.FileInputStream("D:\\models"+ pos);
opennlp.tools.postag.POSModel pOSModel = new pennlp.tools.postag.POSModel(modelInpStream);
```

It throws this error:

> InvalidFormatException
>
> The profile data stream has an invalid format!

Can anybody tell me what is the problem in the above code?

Comment: The error implies that `en-pos-maxext.bin` is not in the correct format.  Have you checked it?

Comment: i ma using opennlp-1.5 models, can you tell me how can i check correct format.

Comment: i have also downloaded other models those are working fine,but with this en-pos-maxext.bin i am getting problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found solution. actually problem is in `en-pos-maxent.bin` zip file.

i have downloaded 1.5 models in which every model has only 2 contents. but `en-pos-maxent.bin` has 3 contents, so just removing `tags.tagdict` file form `zip` file my problem is solved.